# Firebase favicon display inconsistency?

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting, favicon

I'm hosting a basic static site with Firebase Hosting and Google Domains. After deploying on Firebase, I added a custom domain for the site inside of the hosting console.

The site and images work great. However, the favicon displays properly everywhere except on iOS Safari. When I enter in the custom domain name (example.com), it doesn't display the favicon. However, when I enter in the custom domain name with /index.html (example.com/index.html), it displays properly! Or, when I enter the Firebase Hosting URL (example.web.app) it also displays.

My guess is something is happening when the site redirects to the custom domain...I've tried everything from putting the favicon in an images folder, in the root file, adding apple-touch-icons, responsive favicon sizes, etc. But nothing seems to work to resolve the issue on iOS Safari. This is what I have in my HTML file for the index.html in the 'public' folder:

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

Any chance folks have an idea of how to fix this? Or perhaps there's a way to force the site to open the specific index.html page? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We can't see what you've done or if you've done something wrong. It's highly unlikely that this is a problem with Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I just edited to add the standard HTML that I have in my index.html file in the 'public' folder

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.